# gcc compiler in ubuntu

Tags: gcc, c

I created a simple C program which prints "Hello world" as output and saved it as `test.c`.

Compiled it in terminal as `gcc -o test test.c` & run it as `./test` but the there is no output showing.

If the same program saved as `try.c` and any(but not as test) it compiles & runs perfectly.

Why? Is there a problem with a compiled C binary having the name `test`?

Comment: Is there any other file named `test` in your working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is a bash program called test and when run it does nothing without arguments (do a quick man test in terminal to see more about it).  That is why renaming worked :)

Lots of people do not know 'test' is a program too, best not to name scripts and such 'test'

Comment: `test` is actually a program made to test conditions.

Comment: Irrelevant, since the OP ran it as `./test`, specifying the path and thus avoiding the builtin and the `test` program.

Answer (score -1):

There is a shell program called `test` that tests conditions, which is why you couldn't run the binary. It is a shell built-in specified by POSIX that also exists in many other shells such as `ksh` (Korn shell) and `ash` (Almquist shell). Bash is made to (mostly) conform to the POSIX specification itself. The `test` utility is made to check for various attributes for a file or for various string and numeric tests. Examples:

```
test -e FILE  # if the file exists in some form
test -f FILE  # if the file exists as a regular file (not a directory, symlink, etc.)

test -n "$str"  # if the string has a length greater than 0
test -z "$str"  # if the string is an empty string

test "$str" = "foo"  # equivalent to `str == "foo"` in C

test $num -lt 10  # if the number is less than 10
test $num -ge 10  # if the number is greater than or equal to 10
test $num -eq 10  # if the number equals 10
```

Long story short, it is probably in your best interest to rename your program instead of trying to run a file Bash refuses to even acknowledge the mere possibility of existence. ;-)